# Replanifier une réunion durant/en

Tags: grammaire

Est-ce que c'est correct de dire:

*Je ne peux pas y assister, pourrais-tu replanfier la visite durant le mois Janvier?*

Pour dire qu'en mois de Janvier je peux y assister et demander la replanification de la date de la visite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replanifier en janvier, pour une visite on ne sait quand:

- *Pourrais-tu replanifier la visite **au mois de janvier?*** ou
- *Pourrais-tu replanifier la visite **durant le mois de janvier?*** ou
- *Pourrais-tu replanifier la visite **pendant le mois de janvier?***

Toutes ces tournures sont imprécises. D'un côté elles signifient que c'est la recherche de la date qui interviendra en janvier. Ce n'est pas ce que vous vouliez dire. D'un autre côté on va corriger et comprendre ce que vous vouliez dire.

---

Replanifier dès que possible, pour une visite en janvier.

*Pourrais-tu replanifier la visite **pour le mois de janvier?***

On peut aussi dire:

- *Pourrais-tu **repousser la visite à janvier?*** ou
- **... décaler à janvier?** (ma préférence) ou
- **... déplacer la visite à janvier?**.

---

Contrairement à l'anglais, en français ni les noms de mois, ni les noms de jours ne prennent de majuscules, ce sont des noms communs.

Answer (score 0):

Prenez garde à respecter la concordance des temps.

Avec la structure `en Janvier` il ne faut pas ajouter d'autres mots.

Vous pouvez utiliser la tournure suivante:

> Je ne *pourrai* pas y assister, pourrais-tu replanifier la visite **en** janvier?

Votre formulation `durant le mois de janvier` est correcte mais selon moi un peu formelle. Je vous suggère d'utiliser `pendant le mois de janvier` à la place, qui me semble plus courant.

> Je ne *pourrai* pas y assister, pourrais-tu replanifier la visite **pendant le mois de** Janvier?

Si on veut éviter les répétitions du verbe pouvoir, voilà quelques exemples de phrases possibles:

> Je ne pourrai pas y assister, serait-il possible de replanifier la visite **au mois de** janvier ?

> Je ne serai pas disponible à ces dates, serait-il possible de planifier une autre visite **courant** janvier ?